# html5のcanvasを使って画像を読み込み、読み込んだ画像に装飾し、pngなどの形式で書きだしたい

Tags: javascript, html5, cors

js初心者です。
HTML5のcanvasを使って
読み込んだ画像に何かしらの装飾(fillTextなどで画像にテキストを描画)を行い、
canvasごとpngなどの形式で書き出したいと考えています。

しかし、下記エラーが出て上手く書き出せません。ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
Script from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

ソースコードは以下のとおりです。

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>読み込んだ画像にテキストを描画</title>
  <script src="myscript.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>読み込んだ画像にテキストを描画</h1>
<form>
<input type="button" value="canvasに描画" onclick="draw()">
</form>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400">
  Canvasに対応したブラウザを使用してください。
</canvas>
<!-- <form>
<input type="button" value="画像に変換" onclick="chgImg()">
</form> -->
<div><img id="newImg"></div>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

## myscript.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(){
  var img = new Image();
  //ローカルの画像を読み込む
  img.src = 'test.png';
  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  }
  ctx.font = 'bold 20px Verdana';
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText('test', 20, 20, 200);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("newImg").src = dataURL;
  console.log(dataURL);
  chgImg();
}

// 取得したtoDataURL()をpngに変換
function chgImg() {
  var png = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("newImg").src = png;
}
```

Comment: 環境及び、デバッグ方法を記述しましょう。もしかして、サーバも立てずにそのままHTMLをブラウザで開いて実行していませんか？既に付いている解答で問題はないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

index.htmlについて、以下の2点を修正してみてください。

- head要素内にあるscript要素を削除する。
- body要素の閉じタグの位置を正しくする。

これで動作するようになります。以下のようになるでしょう。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>読み込んだ画像にテキストを描画</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>読み込んだ画像にテキストを描画</h1>
<form>
<input type="button" value="canvasに描画" onclick="draw()">
</form>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400">
  Canvasに対応したブラウザを使用してください。
</canvas>
<!-- <form>
<input type="button" value="画像に変換" onclick="chgImg()">
</form> -->
<div><img id="newImg"></div>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ちなみに、もしChromeから「ファイルを開く」でindex.htmlを開いた場合は、script要素のcrossorigin属性は削除してください。今回のコードの場合に開こうとしているtest.pngは同じドメインから読み込まれるので、そもそもcrossorigin属性の指定は必要ありません。仮にcrossdomain属性を使ってCORSを適用したい場合は、「ファイルを開く」ではなく、何らかのウェブサーバに配置して"http://"で読み込む必要があります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。色々な凡ミスをしていました。。しかしまた別のエラーが出て上手く動きません。
`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: 僕が貼ったindex.html、ご提示のmyscript.jsそのまま、そして手元にあった画像ファイルの名前を変えたtest.png、これら3つを同じディレクトリに置いて、index.htmlをChromeやsafariの「ファイルを開く」で読み込ませたら、ちゃんと動作しました。また、3つのファイルを置いたディレクトリで python -m SimpleHTTPServer で簡易Webサーバを立ち上げて http://127.0.0.1:8000/ でアクセスしても、ちゃんと動作しました。